# How to subscribe an RSS feed for the whole forum?

Tags: support

I started to organize new posts for SE with an RSS feeder. Since there are not that many post for SE.CS I would like to subscribe to a feed that contains all questions.

I know how to do this for certain tags, but I couldn't figure out how to subscribe to all questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a link to a “recent questions feed” near the bottom right of the [main page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). The feed link is simply https://cs.stackexchange.com/feeds

Comment: Thanks. I was blind.

Comment: Actually, if you are looking for the *newest* question there is no RSS icon. That's why I had problems finding it in the first place.